# Call is ambiguous error - Dice Game

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, error-handling

Hi i'm trying to make a dice game and keep getting this error, not sure what it is or if there is something wrong with my algorithm. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :) It shows an error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'Form1.UpdateGameStatus(int)' and 'Form1.UpdateGameStatus(int)'

```
    private int UpdateGameStatus(int sumDice)
    {

        if (sumDice == 2)
        if (sumDice == 3)
        if (sumDice == 14) 
            lblSum.Text = ("You lost!");
        if (sumDice == 9)
        if (sumDice == 10)
            lblSum.Text = ("You're winner!");
        if (sumDice == 0)
            lblSum.Text = ("Roll again please!");
        return; 

    }

    int point = 0;
    int gamestatus = 0;
    private void UpdateGameStatus(int sumDice)
    {
        while (sumDice == 4 || sumDice == 5 || sumDice == 6 || sumDice==||sumDice == 9 || sumDice == 10)

            point = sumDice;

        if (sumDice == point)
            lblSum.Text = ("You're winner!");
        gamestatus = 1;
        if (sumDice == 7)
            lblSum.Text = ("You lost!");
        gamestatus = -1;
        return;
    }
    private void btnRollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int die1 = 0, die2 = 0;
        RollDice(out die1, out die2);
        UpdateGameStatus(sumDice);     
   }   
}
}
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand?

Comment: I am told to use both void and int, but it doesn't let me. Is there any way to use both with the same parameter and name?

Comment: The error message specifically answers that question.

Answer (score 3):

You have two methods with the same signature:

```
private void UpdateGameStatus(int sumDice)
```

and

```
private int UpdateGameStatus(int sumDice)
```

The compiler can't know which one you mean. They have different return types, but those are not part of the signature.

Comment: Yes is there any way to make it use both? or Can I only use one. I am confused on this.

Comment: You can have both methods, but they can't be named the same, or at least not take the same parameters. So either rename one of them or give one different parameters. That would let the compiler know when you are calling each. For example, you could rename the first method `GetGameStatus(int)`.

Comment: NO you cannot use both if they both have the same name and same input.  Rename the one you don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what's wrong: you are making an ambiguous call to `UpdateGameStatus`. You have two methods, both named `UpdateGameStatus` that both take an integer value. Why don't you just have one version that returns the sum of the dice and also sets the game status? That would solve your problem. You're duplicating code unnecessarily here.

**Edit:** I also noticed that your first method doesn't actually update the game status at all, so if you do want to keep both, consider renaming that one.

**Edit 2:** To summarize what was mentioned in the comments (and to go beyond just the error message), you seem to have some unnecessary code duplication. Think about what you really want this method to do. Do you want it to set the text to `"you lose!"`? Do you want it to track the `gamestatus` variable (1, 0, or -1)? Do you want it to return the `gamestatus` variable? Figure out exactly what you want this method to do/return and try to remove the duplicated code.

Comment: @Flow101 it seems (as far as I can tell) that the void one just does some of what the integer one does already. I'd recommend using the integer one, having it update the game status/ output message based on the result of the roll, and then also return the result of the roll. I'm not sure exactly where this is used, but just try to think about exactly what these functions do and how you use the data. Use the int one if you care about the return value (1, 0, or -1) and the void one if you don't (you only care about setting the gamestatus)

Comment: @Flow101 In other words, combine them; take the best of each and put them together. You're going to have to make the call on what is important yourself, you're the one designing the program.